# Can't open a window in netbeans with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, lwjgl

I'm trying to write a small platformer game in Java.  Nothing big, more of a practice exercise for other things.  However, I keep running into an issue trying to use OpenGL for graphics.  My IDE is Netbeans v.8.2, and I'm using LWJGL to access OpenGL.  When I try to run the basic 'test' code LWJGL provides(https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) it won't run.  The error I'm getting is:

[LWJGL] GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error
    Description : WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL

This is really weird though, as I know my GC and driver do support OpenGL.  I can run Minecraft which uses it(not the best test I know), and I've confirmed using GPU Caps Viewer that my driver( Intel(R) HD Graphics) supports OpenGL 3.1.  It's driving me crazy, and I've spent days looking for anything like this online, but all I can find are extrememly outdated posts and sources that don't seem to apply to my situation.  OpenGL seems to be the perfect tool for the graphics of this project, and I'd really rather not switch over to something else, or re-write the program in something like C++ just to use it. So I'm turning to the brilliance of StackOverFlow.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try using [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html) and the [FXGL](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL) library. JavaFX is a cross platform, Java standard manner to use modern graphic card graphics.

Comment: I hadn't actually heard of FXGL, but looking over the docs it seems like a good alternative.  I'm gong to leave this question open a bit longer while I dig into this, but thank you for the great suggestion!

Comment: Okay, so after reviewing FXGL, it looks like this isn't quite the route I want to go.  Half the point of this project is to get a look at building most of the game's structure myself.  I just need something a little better than Swing, and FXGL has a lot of stuff built in already.  All of the tutorials I've found are also pretty out of date with the current version.  However, the graphics portion is built entirely with JavaFX, so I think that's what I'll be using to handle the graphics in my project.

Answer (score 0):

With the information available in the question, this is most likely the second of the two cases here: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/119#issuecomment-138078724

To reiterate, Intel dropped support for their HD Graphics 2000/3000 GPUs, and it looks like something in Java 8u60 broke support. I would first try making sure everything is up to date (GPU drivers, Java, LWJGL), and if that doesn't work, try downgrading below 8u60.

It looks like there's also a driver-side patch from Marcinosoft at the bottom of that issue that you can try installing as well before downgrading.